How to debug Gazebo Garden crashing on loading a robot description?
ROS2 Humble
Gazebo Garden
I'm trying to load a robot description into Gazebo Garden in my Humble install. I'm following the instructions on how to migrate from Gazebo Classic to Garden. The xacros are unchanged and load fine into rviz2. But when I try to spin up gz sim with an empty world, and then tries loading the robot model, gz crashes - but the launch script thinks it exited normally.
It's actually Ruby that crashes:
ruby3.0 assert failure: gz sim server: ./dart/dynamics/BoxShape.cpp:43: dart::dynamics::BoxShape::BoxShape(const Vector3d&): Assertion `_size[0] > 0.0' failed.
But I have no idea what specifically failed or how to sleuth that.
The last messages left in the gazebo log indicate it may have been trying to process a collision mesh. When I enable visibility of the collision mesh in rviz2 it all looks fine.
here is the gazebo log:
(2024-07-18T20:46:20.987966586) (2024-07-18T20:46:20.987975735) [Msg] Gazebo Sim Server v7.7.0
(2024-07-18T20:46:20.990791890) (2024-07-18T20:46:20.990803386) [Msg] Loading SDF world file[/usr/share/gz/gz-sim7/worlds/empty.sdf].
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.78984915) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.78997035) [Msg] Serving entity system service on [/entity/system/add]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.248459321) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.248469876) [Dbg] [Physics.cc:880] Loaded [gz::physics::dartsim::Plugin] from library [/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-physics-6/engine-plugins/libgz-physics-dartsim-plugin.so]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.248527233) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.248532615) [Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:74] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::Physics] for entity [1]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.251545796) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.251556393) [Msg] Create service on [/world/empty/create]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.251689413) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.251697463) [Msg] Remove service on [/world/empty/remove]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.251821608) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.251829150) [Msg] Pose service on [/world/empty/set_pose]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.251929101) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.251936352) [Msg] Pose service on [/world/empty/set_pose_vector]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.252102662) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.252110291) [Msg] Light configuration service on [/world/empty/light_config]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.252315032) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.252322729) [Msg] Physics service on [/world/empty/set_physics]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.252472990) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.252480351) [Msg] SphericalCoordinates service on [/world/empty/set_spherical_coordinates]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.252542975) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.252549230) [Msg] Enable collision service on [/world/empty/enable_collision]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.252608193) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.252614168) [Msg] Disable collision service on [/world/empty/disable_collision]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.252788653) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.252795920) [Msg] Material service on [/world/empty/visual_config]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.252914746) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.252921410) [Msg] Material service on [/world/empty/wheel_slip]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.252949187) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.252954659) [Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:74] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::UserCommands] for entity [1]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.255911863) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.255921976) [Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:74] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster] for entity [1]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.259282853) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.259293364) [Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:74] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::Contact] for entity [1]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.260925781) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.260939041) [Msg] Loaded level [3]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.263521392) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.263533574) [Msg] Serving world controls on [/world/empty/control], [/world/empty/control/state] and [/world/empty/playback/control]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.263926167) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.263938953) [Msg] Serving GUI information on [/world/empty/gui/info]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.263962054) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.263967990) [Msg] World [empty] initialized with [1ms] physics profile.
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.264425046) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.264433924) [Msg] Serving world SDF generation service on [/world/empty/generate_world_sdf]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.264654064) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.264678358) [Msg] Serving world names on [/gazebo/worlds]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.266609056) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.266663320) [Msg] Resource path add service on [/gazebo/resource_paths/add].
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.470268472) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.470278256) [Msg] Resource path get service on [/gazebo/resource_paths/get].
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.470488551) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.470497414) [Msg] Resource path resolve service on [/gazebo/resource_paths/resolve].
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.470595164) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.470602572) [Msg] Resource paths published on [/gazebo/resource_paths].
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.470761461) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.470769333) [Msg] Server control service on [/server_control].
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.470912119) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.470919779) [Msg] Found no publishers on /stats, adding root stats topic
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.471073916) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.471081587) [Msg] Found no publishers on /clock, adding root clock topic
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.472093892) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.472104261) [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:503] Creating PostUpdate worker threads: 3
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.472133137) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.472140027) [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:514] Creating postupdate worker thread (0)
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.472245105) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.472252733) [Dbg] [SimulationRunner.cc:514] Creating postupdate worker thread (1)
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.596077101) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.596087919) [Msg] DiffDrive subscribing to twist messages on [/model/pioneer3at/cmd_vel]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.596115957) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.596121921) [Dbg] [SystemManager.cc:74] Loaded system [gz::sim::systems::DiffDrive] for entity [10]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.596280116) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.596286923) [Dbg] [UserCommands.cc:1263] Created entity [10] named [pioneer3at]
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.611021292) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.611031567) [Dbg] [SDFFeatures.cc:328] Mesh construction from an SDF has not been implemented yet for dartsim. Use AttachMeshShapeFeature to use mesh shapes.
(2024-07-18T20:46:21.611049707) (2024-07-18T20:46:21.611054325) [Dbg] [SDFFeatures.cc:843] The geometry element of collision [base_link_collision] couldn't be created

prior searches on the final 2 lines in the log seem to show that these messages aren't always indicative of the real issue.

It was due to a gazebo classic xacro construction that used to be legal:
<collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <geometry>
        <!--<box size="0 0 0"/>-->
    </geometry>
</collision>

In modern gazebo this is no longer allowed. Giving the box element a non-zero size or replacing it with a mesh did the trick.
